# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath error - when selecting item again

Tags: uitableview, xcode4, uialertview, didselectrowatindexpath

Loaded a list of items on to the UITableview and was able to click and show an alert for the row selected . But however after saying "ok" on the alert and i reclick on the already selected row my code breaks down saying "Thread 1:Program received signal:EXC_BAD_ACCESS".please take a look at the code below.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *playerselected = [exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *video = [playerselected valueForKey:@"video"];

    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You have selected %@", video];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Player selected" 
                                                    message:msg 
                                                   delegate:self 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];    

    [alert show];     
    [alert release];
    [video release];
    [msg release]; 

}
```

PLease suggest me what could be the issue here.

Comment: OK, I've taken a look. Is there any question in particular you had in mind? Just kidding, although it does help if you ask a specific question, and give as much detail as possible to help us solve your problem (which line the error is occurring on for example). Just dumping code with little explanation does not tend to be a good incentive for other people to help.

Comment: Sry MAc ..corrected the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't release `video`.

When you retrieve a value from an `NSDictionary` you don't own it unless you explicitly `retain` it.

To be more specific, when you retrieve your string it is still owned by the dictionary. When you `release` it, you are releasing an object that you do not own, resulting in it being over-released. As a result it is deallocated, and when you next try to access it the memory is no longer valid and your app crashes.